# How to generate table with nested Array objects without Nested Table and keeping columns aligned in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to generate a table with nested Array object, apart from using nested table, which can't proper align the header in the outer table with the column in inner table.

example class:

```
 export class Result{
    id?: string;
    result?: string;
 }

 export class Entity{
    result?: Array<Result>;
    name?: string;
 }

 export class Test{
    entity?: Array<Entity>;
 }
```

data:

```
{
   "test":{
      "entity":[
         {
            "name":"ABC",
            "result":[
               {
                  "id":"123",
                  "result":"AAA"
               },
               {
                  "id":"456",
                  "result":"SSS"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"CDE",
            "result":[
               {
                  "id":"789",
                  "result":"BBB"
               },
               {
                  "id":"012",
                  "result":"CCC"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Expected table structure:
[Expected table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vgSf.jpg)

In the html template, how do I generate rows in the inner loop of the "test.result" object? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
<tr *ngFor="let test of test.entity; let i=index;">
                    <td>{{test.name}}</td>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let result of test.reslt; let j=index;"> // how to generate more row here?
                            <td style="width: 19%; text-align:center;">{{result.id}}</td>
                            <td style="width: 19%; text-align:center;">{{result.name}}</td>
                    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-template` with nested `ng-container`s and pass `index` value to template.

Like following:

```
<ng-template #rowTemplateOutlet let-index="index" let-entity="entity" let-result="result">
    <tr>
        <td [attr.rowspan]="entity.result.length" *ngIf="index == 0">
            {{entity.name}}
        </td>

        <td style="width: 19%; text-align:center;">{{result.id}}</td>
        <td style="width: 19%; text-align:center;">{{result.result}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngFor="let entity of test.entity;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let result of entity.result; let i=index;">


        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="rowTemplateOutlet; context:{entity: entity, result: result, index: i}"> 
        </ng-container>

    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Hope that helps

Here's working stackblitz link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1k3yn7